# PineScript: Not getting the current exchange time in time_close function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am seeing a weird behavior with the `time_close` function.
Definitely I am doing some mistake not able to understand.

In PineScript v5, I am trying to get the current bar's closing time in my exchange in India's timezome. Which is GMT+5:30 or 'Asia/Kolkata'.

This is my code:

```
currtime = str.format("[{0,date,HH:mm:ss dd.MM.yyyy}]\n", time_close(timeframe.period, syminfo.session, syminfo.timezone))
label.new(bar_index, low, str.tostring(currtime))
```

The timezone is 'Asia/Kolkata'. I have printed it to test.

However the time is still coming in GMT like 3:30 PM (our exchange closing candle) is showing as 10:00 AM.

What's the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the third parameter of the time_close function as below

```
time_close(timeframe.period, syminfo.session, "GMT+5:30")
```

Comment: Did not help. Still getting the same results.